# Big query google analytics dataset table limit link

Tags: dataset, google-bigquery, limit, analytics

Recently, we linked big query with Google Analytics. A data set with lots of tables was created. It is accessible, but we noted that not all dates were carried out.

A table shows:

```
ga_sessions_(478), it means 478 days from now, counting backwards
```

It points to middle 2015, but if we enter to Google Analytics, we can see data from 2015, 2014 and earlier.

Now we are using big query to get data from Google Analytics and we can't access to 2014 data that we know does exist.

Why are there limits for the periods? Why are the dataset/tables limited?

Comment: Hi there, since you already have premium package, you should directly contact the support personnel who setup for you. They can answer these, and not the community.

Answer (score 1):

When you link a GA view(profile) with Google BigQuery only smaller of 13 months data or 5 billion sessions would be backfilled to bigquery. This limitation is displayed when you try to link GA view with bigquery.

As suggested by @Pentium10 you can definitely ask GAP support if you need data for more than the limit specified.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Backfill data for Bigquery is now revised to 13 months or **10 billion** instead 5 billion earlier.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092?hl=en#backfill